# Flutter Failed to build and run iOS app only in physical iOs device

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

i'm trying build and run a "Counter App" (the default app when you create a flutter project), i can run the project in android and iOs simulators, on physics devices works in android perfectly but when i run the project in vscode i got an error.

The output when i run the project is:

```
Downloading libimobiledevice...
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: FSB8SU7R5X
Xcode build done.                                           16.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2021-06-30 22:16:22.665 xcodebuild[43211:324927]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 281a05c1d363c04aed318582d30866afde2dd04c was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7faac3b77c10>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7faac0c416c0>{number = 2, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    2021-06-30 22:16:22.867 xcodebuild[43211:324928]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 281a05c1d363c04aed318582d30866afde2dd04c was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7faac3b77c10>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7faac3b69fe0>{number = 6, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    2021-06-30 22:16:22.991 xcodebuild[43211:324928]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 281a05c1d363c04aed318582d30866afde2dd04c was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7faac3b77c10>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7faac3b69fe0>{number = 6, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Removed stale file '/Users/jromero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-flkwoylypfarbpbtarvmoxfypnce/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app'
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried cleaning the project (flutter clean, get the packages and run again) but there is not working :c.

Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en)
    • Flutter version 2.2.2 at /Users/jromero/development/flutter
    • Framework revision d79295af24 (3 weeks ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
    • Dart version 2.13.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jromero/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/jromero/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.1.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 57.0.5
    • Dart plugin version 211.7665

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!
```

Any help is welcome c:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is a bit of a late answer but what has helped me in these situations is to

1. Run "flutter clean" in the terminal
2. In some cases, it'll help to clear your project's files cache...can be done by opening your command shortcut on vscode(shift+command+p or shift+control+p) then search for "Clear Editor History"
3. Assuming you have a Mac and pods installed and you have updated any pubsec packages, an optional additional step that has worked for the most part is to delete your "Podfile.lock" file under your Flutter Project iOS folder, assuming it has already been generated upon previous builds, then close your IDE. Then in your terminal, navigate to your cd `<pathToProject>/<ios>` *important that you navigate to your iOS subfolder* and run `pod install --repo-update`

-all the best